# What is the maximum precision representable value for a given double value on a machine?

Tags: c++, floating-point, epsilon

Couple of questions from below code:

a) What does std::numeric_limits::digits10 denote?
b) If (a) represents max 10 digits double number re-presentable on a machine then we can keep getting more and more precision by just adding +1, +2 and then whats the maximum re-presentable double value on a machine? How can be display that? i.e what std::numeric_limits::digits10 + MaxN?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>


int main(void)
{
  double d1 = 0.1;
  double d2 = 0.2;
  double d3 = d1 + d2;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1) << "Sum 0.1 + 0.2 = " << d3 << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 2) << "Sum 0.1 + 0.2 = " << d3 << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 3) << "Sum 0.1 + 0.2 = " << d3 << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 4) << "Sum 0.1 + 0.2 = " << d3 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remember that there's a *HUGE* difference between the "precision" when you print a number (e.g. `std::setprecision`, basically just "presentation") and the *ACTUAL* mathematical precision available in your floating point number ([std::numeric_limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/)).  To answer your question: `digits10: Number of digits (in decimal base) that can be represented without change.
Equivalent to FLT_DIG, DBL_DIG or LDBL_DIG for floating types.`

Comment: @paulsm4 - What do you mean by "digits10: Number of digits (in decimal base) that can be represented without change." What is the meaning of "representation without change"? Who is changing what?

Comment: When you convert a real number into a fp one, digits start to differ from some position due to finite precision. Those before that position are represented "without change".

Comment: This will provides some background [The Shortest Decimal String That Round-Trips May Not Be The Nearest](https://www.exploringbinary.com/the-shortest-decimal-string-that-round-trips-may-not-be-the-nearest/).  Other articles on the site tagged `Floating-point` will provide more information (and make your head hurt) [Exploring Binary - Floating-point](https://www.exploringbinary.com/tag/floating-point/) .

Answer (score 1):

> What does `std::numeric_limits::digits10 denote?`

`double` is typically 64-bits and can exactly represent about 2<sup>64</sup> different values.

Text like `"0.1"`, `"3.1415926535897932384626433832795"`, etc. has infinite possibilities.

Convert text to `double` and then back to text, do we get the same text (*round-tripping*)?  This will not work for all possible text.

Take a sub-set of text possibilities, say only those with up to N leading significant decimal digits and with a limited exponent range.

`numeric_limits<double>::digits10` (e.g. 15) is that N that allow for all successful round-tripping.

---

> What is the maximum precision representable value for a given double value on a machine?

Typical [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is encoded using base-2 and has a maximum precision of 53 significant *binary* digits.

> can keep getting more and more precision by just adding ...

Select `double` values, written in decimal, take more than `N` significant digits to write *exactly*.  I'd say up to about [754](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485).

Writing a `double` to `numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10`  (e.g. 17) significant decimal digits is sufficient to distinguish it from all other `double`.

A quality `double` to text function will certainly and correctly write at least `max_digits10` decimal digits.  Beyond that it is up to the implementation.  To meet [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), I am certain the minimum is `max_digits10 + 3`.

---

`numeric_limits<double>::digits10` differs from `numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10` because the `double` encoding using base 2 differs from *text* as base 10.  The `double` values are not nicely distributed along base 10 values.

Comment: The below statement flew over my head ---> "numeric_limits<double>::digits10 differs from numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10 because the double encoding using base 2 differs from text as base 10. The double values are not nicely distributed along base 10 values."